# Qt: Material Design is not running

Tags: android, qt, qml, material-design, qtquickcontrols2

I am using Qt 5.7. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. My basic code is here:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
  visible: true
  width: 300
  height: 300
  title: qsTr("Hello World")

  Material.theme: Material.Dark
  Material.accent: Material.Green

  Column {
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    RadioButton { text: qsTr("Radio Button 1") }
    RadioButton { text: qsTr("Radio Button 2") }
    RadioButton { text: qsTr("Radio Button 3") }
  }
}
```

I use material design but when I ran this app on the desktop I see Qt default style, not material design: [Image Link](https://s14.postimg.org/6hum408rl/img.png). I did not get any error or warning. When I ran this app on the Android Device (tablet) and Genymotion, I see same result. I am using NVIDIA card and my driver is X.Org (open source). But when I used NVIDIA 340.98 driver, I get this warning: `"NV-GLX" missing on display ":0"` and I see this app style is not material design on the desktop, Android device or Genymotion. How can I solve this problem? How can I use material design on Qt/QML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing a style and setting attributes for it doesn't make the application run with that style. You can import multiple styles in the same file, to set style-specific attributes for each of them. Those take effect when the application is run with that specific style. See [Using Styles in Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html#using-styles-in-qt-quick-controls-2) for the available methods to select a specific style.

Comment: Thanks, I used [qputenv](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qputenv): `qputenv("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE", "material");`